# JQuery issue on IE ... works fine with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a loading image next to a button, on clicking the button the image is shown until one function is called after that the image is taken out.

```
$("#done").click(function() {
    $("#load_image").show(); // show the loading image 
    $.fn.myfunction('test'); // function call
    $("#load_image").hide(); // hide the image after the function call is done
)};
```

This works as expected on firefox but on IE the whole operation is done at once, and the image is not shown. It works fine if I `alert` or `return false` in the middle.

I have this added to my code

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

also tried to set a timeout, to force the image but doesn't work

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#load_image").hide();
}, 1000);
```

Even that isn't working, Not sure that I am using it right. Looked at few related queries and solutions but I am unable to fix this. Please help.

Comment: what is `.myfunction` doing?

Comment: What console in IE says?

Comment: myfunction is doing some validation for the page before moving onto the next page... @Daniel

Comment: Console does say that the image is getting loaded but there is no sign of it because in IE the whole process is taking place at once... i.e... show_image+function_call+hide_image = no image :(

Comment: Atleast give a reason before voting down the question...

Comment: The downvotes may be because you haven't produced enough code to allow us to reproduce the issue. I would suggest adding a stack snippet or JS Fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks for asking that question... that headed me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Check your myfunction(). comment it and check if your code is working else there is something messing in your myfunction().

Comment: I commented that function and tried to just load the image and hide, it isn;t working... @Harsh ... Any other ideas??

Comment: comment your js and first check if image is loading in IE or not.

Comment: Image is getting loaded on IE, the problem is the show and hide in the same flow...

Comment: then try to use $("#load_image").css('display','block') & $("#load_image").css('display','none')

Comment: Tried that one as well... works the same way, the show() and hide() is working correctly.